# Unix ksh replace 2nd to last character of a variable

Tags: unix, replace, ksh

I am on a UNIX system that uses the Korn Shell.  I'm a UNIX beginner.  Here is what I want to do:

```
var1=user/hYbMj8d@RM1
```

I would like to replace only the 2nd to the last letter, which will always be an `M` if that matters, and change it to an `O`, and and store this as a new it into a new variable.

So the new variable will contain:

```
var2=user/hYbMj8d@RO1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `sed`:

`sed 's/M\(.$\)/O\1/'`

Full solution for storing updated `var1` in `var2`:

```
 var2=`echo $var1 | sed 's/M\(.$\)/O\1/'`
```

Explanation: using `sed` replace command: `s/<find>/<replace>/`. It searches for `M.$` pattern where `$` is EOL - so it will be 2nd character from the end. Then it captures remainder after `M` character (escaped parentheses - in `sed` capture groups should be escaped) and replaces it with `O` character and remainder after `M` - what was captured (it is special reference `\1` - captured group #1).

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the answer and more importantly, the explanation to what it's doing!!!